# test function inside function using karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Below is function inside controller,

```
self.myTest = myTest ();
function myTest (){
self.myval = true;

    function innerFun(val) {
    return val;
    }
    innerFun(2);
    }
```

Here is my spec file , I'm using  karma test runner to test angular code,below is code in spec file.

```
 it('should make a call inner fun and ret val ', function() {
    spyOn(ctr, 'myTest ').and.callThrough();
    // ?? How can i test function inside myTest
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would only test your publicly available methods.  That is, you would setup conditions so that the call of myTest() would trigger the condition and call to innerFun()

However, I've had cases where I've needed to violate that rule.  In these cases, I need to make the inner function a function on the outer scope:

```
function innerFun(val){
    return val;
}

function myTest(){
   innerFun(2);
}
```

and then some place else write code that looks something like this: (I'm assuming you are using jasmine as your test platform)

```
if(window.jasmine){
    self.innerFun = innerFun;
}
```

which makes innerFun public while you are testing with Jasmine.

The purest, won't like this answer, but sometimes you need to break the rules.

Comment: you mean the innerFun should be outside my Test(),  i.e self.innerFun = innerfun()